# Polymer paper-fab: How to make it float inside paper-drawer-panel content

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

With reference to the [Polymer todo-list app](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/todo-list), I'm trying to place a paper-fab inside todo-view.html such that scrolling the main contents would result in the fab always floating in the bottom right.

My code looks like this

```
 <paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel">
  <div drawer>

    <!-- Drawer Toolbar -->
    <paper-toolbar id="drawerToolbar"></paper-toolbar>

    <!-- Drawer Content -->
    <paper-menu class="list" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
     ...
    </paper-menu>
  </div>
  <paper-header-panel main>

    <!-- Main Toolbar -->
    <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
      ...
    </paper-toolbar>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div class="content">

      <todo-list todos="{{todos}}"
                 filter-by="{{route}}"
                 on-delete-todo="deleteTodo">
      </todo-list>

      <todo-input on-add-todo="addTodo"></todo-input>
      <!-- fab does not float. -->
       <paper-fab mini icon="favorite" title="heart"></paper-fab>
    </div>
  </paper-header-panel>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

How do i make the paper-fab to always float bottom right even while I'm scrolling through the contents?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Add to your CSS.

```
paper-fab {
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 70px;
      position: fixed;
      right: 25px;
      bottom: 25px;          
     }
```

And your tag is something like this:

```
  <paper-fab icon="favorite" title="heart"></paper-fab>
```